# SNMP Broadcast on Windows

Tags: networking, network-programming, snmp, broadcast, winsnmp

I'm writing an SNMP agent in windows. The agent responds fine simple get and get-next request sent directly to computer's ip address. But when I do a SNMP broadcast, the computer receives the packet but does not anwer that. Why is that? The firewall is off and the antivirus too.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you create this agent and how you bind to winsock.